# Proving differentiablity of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am a little stuck on the following question:
The question is asking to determine whether the following statement is true or false, and provide a formal proof if it's true, or a counterexample if it's false.

The function is the following:
$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 sin(x)sin(\frac{1}{x})&\text{if}\, x≠0\\
 0&\text{if}\, x=0
\end{cases}
$ 

The statement is: $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

$$$$
After giving it some thought, I have determined that this statement is true, however, I am not really sure how to go about writing a proof, and I am a bit confused.

I thought about calculating the derivative of the function and showing that it's derivative exists, but I'm not sure this is a valid approach.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ f'(0) =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x \sin(1/x)}{x}$$

Since $\sin x /x $ approaches $1$ and $\sin(1/x)$ does not have a limit your function is not differentible at $0$

Comment: I see! So instead of providing a counterexample for this statement, would it be sufficient to break the limit into two separated limits using the properties of a limit to prove it's wrong?